# prolog compare SOS

Tags: prolog

let say i had this two facts.

```
animal(fifi,10).
animal(fofo,20).
```

If i call

```
animal(X,Y).
```

then Prolog will return me

```
X = fifi,
Y = 10 ;
X = fofo,
Y = 20.
```

What I need to do, to let to Prolog only return me the animal X with the highest value of Y according to the fact?

Is there any possible way that it will just display X only for the highest value of Y instead of displaying X and Y together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can build a list of all the animals and their values, then sort the list and take the element you want from it:

```
max_animal(MaxAnimal):-
  findall(Value-Animal, animal(Animal, Value), L),
  keysort(L, Sorted),
  reverse(Sorted, [_-MaxAnimal|_]).
```

Comment: Why `keysort/2` which in this case makes your program sensitive to the order of answers of `animal/2`?

Comment: This program assumes that there is only one maximal value which is what I understood that OP intended. It uses keysort instead of sort because what I wanted to sort were just the Values. If there is only one maximal value then the program is not sensitive to the order of answers of animal/2.

Comment: We have here some magnitude to compare. That might be the height, weight, cost or similar. It is unusual that those are guaranteed to be unique. You would have a point with some id, but those are rarely compared for their magnitude - although they could, i.e. the newest/oldest registration number. Apart from that a `setof/3`, and "last" or `phrase((...,[_-MaxAnimal]),Sorted)`.,

Comment: It really doesn't matter if it's not guaranteed to be unique. If you only want one animal of the set of maximal magnitude and there is no reason to choose one over another then it is ok to be sensitive to the order of animal/2.

Comment: The program is brittle - that is, sensitive to minor changes like reordering the facts.  I doubt a programmer is able to keep in mind all those assumptions you require.

Comment: Reordering of facts is no minor change in prolog. The only assumption in this program is that you want only one result X from the highest value Y of animal(X,Y).

Comment: The more assumptions you impose to use your program properly, the higher the chances that they will be violated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5828/discussion-between-gusbro-and-false)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively :

```
max_animal(MaxAnimal) :-
    findall(Y, animal(X, Y), Ys),
    max_list(Ys, Max),
    animal(MaxAnimal, Max).
```

Comment: +1 Your solution gives us all beasts, not only one arbitrary one!